# Почему JSONModel не выходит вытянуть вложенные ключи?

Tags: objective-c, json

Ув. програмеры! Прошу помощи так как сам уже разуверился в решении данной проблемы. При помощи `JSONModel` хочу получить данные, причем из корневых ключей все выгребает без проблем, тогда как вложения полностью игнорирует.

Ссылка на скрин JSON http://s019.radikal.ru/i624/1412/bd/6f342f5373b1.jpg

Вот собственно код:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
 NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://json-link"];
 NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
op.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

[op setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    [self didReceiveJSON: responseObject];

 } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
 // Handle error
 }];

[op start];
}

-(void)didReceiveJSON:(NSDictionary*)obj
{
    NSArray* results = obj[@"content"];
    /* ?????????????????  Переменная "album_list" не заполняется */
    album_list = [AlbumModel arrayOfModelsFromDictionaries:results];

[self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

И есть вот такие 2 модели:

```
#import "JSONModel.h"

@protocol SongsModel;

@interface RootSongsModel : JSONModel

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* average_rating;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray<SongsModel> *songs;

@end

#import "JSONModel.h"
#import "RootSongsModel.h"

@protocol SongsModel
@end

@interface SongsModel : JSONModel

@property (assign, nonatomic) int* album_id;
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSString* artist_name;
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSString* average_rating;
@property (strong, atomic) RootSongsModel<Optional> *content;

@end
```

Comment: NSString* search_title; не опциональный, а в JSON не вижу этого поля

Comment: В JSON это поле есть, я просто урезал скрин. Но все равно поменял здесь в модели другое поле, которое есть в ссылке.
Не совсем понял про замечание про опциональное поле в модели RootSongsModel. Уточните пожалуйста, что вы имели в виду.

Comment: Про опциональное я имел ввиду search_title, так как не увидел его в JSON. просто JSONModel обычно по тихому генерит ошибку о не возможности отпарсить данные и возвращает nil. В Вашем случае яб воспользовался дебагером и поизучал что происходит на каждом шаге.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду походить по модулям JSON под отладкой?

Answer (score 1):

Вместо вызова метода

```
arrayOfModelsFromDictionaries
```

вызовите метод:

```
arrayOfModelsFromDictionaries:error:
```

и посмотрите что вернет в ошибке. А лучше, обработайте.

Comment: Ок, спасибо. Попробую и отпишусь.

Comment: Подебажил я код, получается в JSONModel.m в методе 
+(NSMutableArray*)arrayOfModelsFromDictionaries:(NSArray*)array error:(NSError**)err
{
    //bail early
    if (isNull(array)) return nil;

    //parse dictionaries to objects
    NSMutableArray* list = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity: [array count]];

    for (NSDictionary* d in array) {

после цикла for переменная "d" пустая (d=0 key/value pairs), следовательно не отрабатывает "Модель". Как еще можно в модели указать использование вложения в JSON ?

Comment: ох как тяжело. сделайте простой проект с вашей траблой и расшарте его. Мана кончилась.